# How to test path parameters of a GET request with NodeJS's supertest?

Tags: node.js, rest, testing, supertest

I've found examples how to test query parameters

e.g.:

```
/api/browser?parameter1=2341&parameter2=5663
```

but I couldn't find how to parametrize a test if I've a path parameter, an URL like this:

```
const ENDPOINT_DETAILS = "/api/browser/:parameter";
app.get(ENDPOINT_DETAILS, function (req, res) {

    logger.info("Endpoint called: " + ENDPOINT_DETAILS);
    var details = {}
    // ... magic
    res.send(details);
}
```

How should my test look like if I don't want to fix my parameter?

```
describe("returns details", function() {

    it("returns status 200", function(done) {

        var sampleData = "sample_detail";

        // this won't work
        restApi.get('/api/browser/:parameter')
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .expect(200, { "text" : "Detail of " + parameter + " is: " + sample_text})
            .end(function(err, res) {
                if (err) throw err;
                done();
            });

    });
});
```

Is it possible to know the value of the `parameter` here, before `restApi.get()` is called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to supply an actual number for `:parameter`. For example

```
restApi.get('/api/browser/1234')
```

The endpoint needs to be supplied with real values after all. `req.params.parameter` will then be 1234 in the endpoint function.

I'm not exactly sure what you mean with not fixing the parameter. Do you want to use a variable to make the test reusable for several parameters? Then I would simply do

```
let parameter = 1234;
restApi.get('/api/browser/' + parameter)
```